# How to duplicate 5 posts out of WP_Query results?

Tags: wp-query, query

If I have done a posts query which has fetched a long list of posts in to the WP_Object `$all_posts`, how, during the output loop, can I pull the next five posts of `$all_posts` in to new WP_Object `$five_posts`?

I'm already successfully using a counter, `$i`, in the loop to identify the position at which this should occur.

What I don't understand is how to get the next five posts in to a `WP_Object`.

I have tried...

```
$five_posts = new WP_Query();
$five_posts->posts = array_slice(
                            $all_posts->posts, 
                            $all_posts->current_position, 
                            $all_posts->current_position + 5
                        );
```

But that results only in the `[posts]` part of the query, sliced as an array, and omits the actual query data, which I'd like to retain.

So, basically, how do I extract five posts out of `$all_posts` in a way that maintains `$five_posts` as a full `WP_Query` object?

Comment: Could you describe what you're hoping to achieve here? Not really sure why you'd need separate `WP_Query` objects for each 5 posts. The main reason you'd want `WP_Query` would be for the properties that can be used for pagination, but if you just want groups of 5 posts, using `array_slice()` with `get_posts()` would be much simpler.

Comment: Custom function `display_showcase_features($showcase_posts)` is reusable function to output an above-the-fold "feature" post block, where `$showcase_posts` is a `WP_Query` object. Below fold, aim is to achieve layout variation in a long list at set intervals by putting groups of five posts through the `same display_showcase_features()`. Doable with a *new* query, but I assumed DB overhead.  Posts as array doesn't work (outputs nothing); `display_showcase_features($showcase_posts)` seems set up for `WP_Query`, ie. `if( $showcase_posts->have_posts() ){ $showcase_posts->the_post();`...